# NGINX : Making two asynchronously calls to a backend server

Tags: nginx, openresty

I want to do the following using NGINX Module : 
Nginx receives a request, checks if it has the key to decode the request in the cache(custom)

- if YES, then decode request, obtain an ID from it and check if there is a value against this ID in a key-value store (asynchronously) and return it in the response
- if NO, then get the new key from the key-value store (asynchronously) and then store this key in the cache and use it to decode the request. Obtain the ID and check if there is a value against this ID in the key-value store(asynchronously) and send it in the response.

I was able to figure out how to do step 1, i wrote an upstream module by referring openresty's nginx module from [github](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module). For achieving step 2 functionality, i tried creating a new upstream request in the process_header() function of the first upstream call (i.e getting the key from the store), but this didn't work. How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 approaches:

1. You may do it all in Lua using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis) library. Here you may find some info [Configure-nginx-to-get-url-from-redis-with-key-and-proxy-the-url-to-other-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882191/configure-nginx-to-get-url-from-redis-with-key-and-proxy-the-url-to-other-server/26897609#26897609)
2. Write nginx C module, use [redis2-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) as upstream module, send subrequest. Take a look at my answer to [Subrequests are not sent or the request hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444425/subrequests-are-not-sent-or-the-request-hangs/30459371#30459371) It shows how to send subrequests.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I tried the 2nd approach that you mention, but it didn't work for me. Is it possible to send nonHTTP request as subrequest ? I want to send a query to [redis](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) as the subRequest.

Comment: and one more thing, the URI which is send as a parameter to ngx_http_subrequest() is getting appended with the working directory of nginx

Comment: Yes, it is possible to send non-HTTP subrequest. Specify an URl which should match your location which use redis2 module as upstream.

Comment: Not sure about "getting appended with the working directory of nginx". Can you use subrequest from nginx config? http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html#nginx-variables-a-detour-to-subrequests

Comment: do you have code that sends only a single subrequest, a simple example from which i can refer to check any mistakes from my side ?

Comment: I already posted examples how to send subrequests for both C code and nginx config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86862/discussion-between-melwin-jose-and-alexander-altshuler).